# How to use async Mysql query with PHP PDO

Tags: php, asynchronous, mysqli, pdo, mysqli-multi-query

The Mysqlnd driver PHP 5.6  have opportunity to use a Async queries http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.reap-async-query.php

How to use Async queries with PDO?

it is not work, code ([PHP asynchronous mysql-query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27240421/php-asynchronous-mysql-query)):

```
$dbConnectionOne = new \PDO($cnn0, $conf['user'], $conf['pass']);
$dbConnectionOne->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$dbConnectionTwo =  new \PDO($cnn0, $conf['user'], $conf['pass']);
$dbConnectionTwo->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$dbConnectionTwo->setAttribute(\PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY, false);


$t = time();
$synchStmt = $dbConnectionOne->prepare('SELECT sleep(2)');
$synchStmt->execute();

$asynchStmt = $dbConnectionTwo->prepare('SELECT sleep(1)');
$asynchStmt->execute();

$measurementConfiguration = array();
foreach ($synchStmt->fetchAll() as $synchStmtRow) {
   print_r($synchStmtRow);
}

while (($asynchStmtRow = $asynchStmt->fetch()) !== false) {
   print_r($asynchStmtRow);
}


$t = time() - $t;

echo 'query execute ', $t, ' sec',PHP_EOL;
```

excepted 2 sec but result = 3 sec

Comment: Look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27240421/php-asynchronous-mysql-query

Comment: it is not work, code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. You cannot use Mysql async queries with PDO. Mysqli is the only choice.

You can use for this either `mysqli_multi_query` or the regular [`query/poll/reap`](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.poll.php) sequence.

Comment: Thanks, I have my wrapper class on PDO and find way of use async in PDO.

Comment: Thx for sharing, but no.